# Finding a differential of a matrix function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

> Find a differential of the following function:
>
> $$f(X) = a^T X B$$
>
> where $B$ and $X$ are $n \times n$ matrices, and $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

We have nothing in our script about it and I wasn't able to figure out anything on the internet so far. I think I got an idea on how to produce a derivative corresponding to a vector, but I do not see where to start to differentiate with respect to a matrix? I have to

1. Show that $g(X)=a^T X^T X B a$ is [zero-negligible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function).
2. Find the derivative of $g(x)$ from $1.$.

How could I approach $1.$?

Comment: @jgon My edit introduced errors. I edited again.

Comment: Thank you. Could you be more precise?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Compute the derivative of $f : \mathbb R^{n \times n} \to \mathbb R^{1 \times n}$?

Comment: I wrote at the beginning , what I wanted to do. Thanks anyway

Comment: all the best. Thanks for the help